# Spring MVC custom authentification

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cas

I need to include Jasig CAS authentification inside a Spring 3.2 MVC web app.

Currently I've got two jars (CAS core client and a company specific extension), a bunch of filters in web.xml.
Once the request is redirected by CAS server, logged profile data is provided by some session attributes.

I'm processing them using a Singleton Service.
Calling this Service is the tricky part. Can I use an Interceptor in order to call my Auth Service on each Controller call ?

I'm quite sure there's a better way using Spring Security, but I can't understand properly how it's suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used an interceptor.

```
@Component
public class InterceptorAuth extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private IAuthService authService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //AuthService checks session for login attributes, given through CAS servlet
        //AuthBean contains login data ; if it's null, login has failed
        AuthBean authBean = authService.getAuthBean(request);
        String reqUri = request.getRequestURI();
        String serviceName = reqUri.substring(reqUri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, reqUri.length());
        String action = request.getParameter("action") != null ? request.getParameter("action") : "";
        //If Login failed, redirect to Error Page (Auth Controller / Error Action)
        //We let through if requested URL is Error Page itself
        //(This allows us to use a dynamic page ; unless we'll use a static HTML page called directly from here)
        if (authBean == null && !serviceName.equals("authError") && !action.equals("errorAuth")) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:auth.ctrl?action=errorAuth"); 
            ModelAndViewDefiningException mvde = new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mv); 
            throw mvde; 
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

Required Spring XML config

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.demo.sample.interceptor.InterceptorAuth"></bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```